# Why does this ignore my variable for no reason?

Tags: variables, lua

`Str1, Str2 = "aardvark", "zebra"
print(Str1 < Str2 and Str1 .. Str2 or Str2 .. Str1)`

The **Output** is : aardvarkzebra
When i remove Str1, the output was still the same 

`Str1, Str2 = "aardvark", "zebra"
print(Str1 < Str2 and Str1 .. Str2 or Str2)`

The *Question* is: Where does my Str1 go?

Comment: [Lua - Ternary Operator](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TernaryOperator)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the lesser than operator on strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples, `Str1 < Str2` is true, so the same expression (`Str1 .. Str2`) gets printed both times. The right operand of `or` is ignored because its left operand is true.